# What is idea to solve this problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $X,Y$ be independent random variable.For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ define $$Q(x,A):= P[\phi (x,Y) \in A ].$$
show $$P[\phi (X,Y) \in A|X ] = Q(X,A)$$ almost surely.

Now assume $\phi$ is either bounded or non-negative. If $h(x := E(\phi(x, Y))$,
then
$$E (\phi (X, Y)|X) = h(X),$$
almost surely.

Comment: I think you want $\phi\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ rather than $R\to R$, and you need a measurability hypothesis.